# Truncated JSON reponse when network is not local

Tags: json, web-services, network-programming

I have used the Python and Django for implementing the server side. When I use a browser in a computer in local network (where the server is connected to) to work with my web-based application, everything is fine. But when I access the application from a computer outside the local network through the Internet, sometimes responses from the web-services are truncated and NOT JSON parsable (specially when the answer is long.)
Here is a sample:

```
Response Headers
     age:1
     connection:keep-alive
     content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
     date:Wed, 26 Jul 2017 09:07:59 GMT
     server:ATS/5.3.0
     set-cookie:sessionid=pdf9t7xvhzd08svsnvpw0vq8xvc10trz; HttpOnly; Path=/
     status:200
     vary:Cookie
     x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
```

Truncated response:

```
[{"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 4, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 12, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "50\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631L1\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f50Ah-VL", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000001", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 5, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 2, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "55\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631L2\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f55Ah-VL", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000002", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 6, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 2, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "60\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631L2\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f60Ah-VL", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000003", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 7, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 717, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "60\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u0628\u0644\u0646\u062f\u067e\u06cc\u06a9\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f 60Ah-VL-Fx", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000004", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 8, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 1, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "66\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631L3\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f66Ah-VL", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000005", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 9, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 1, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "74\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631L3\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f74Ah-VL", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000006", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 10, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 16, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "90\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631L1\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f90Ah-VL", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000007", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 11, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 38, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "50\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 50Ah-N", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000008", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 12, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 1, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "55\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631L2\u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 55Ah-N", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000009", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 13, "MerchandiseSecondName": "\u0636", "StockNumber": 0, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "60\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u0628\u0644\u0646\u062f\u067e\u06cc\u06a9\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 60Ah-N", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000010", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 14, "MerchandiseSecondName": "\u0636", "StockNumber": 0, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "66\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631L3\u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 66Ah-N", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000011", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 15, "MerchandiseSecondName": "\u0636", "StockNumber": 0, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "70\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u0628\u0644\u0646\u062f\u067e\u06cc\u06a9\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 70Ah-N", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000012", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 16, "MerchandiseSecondName": "\u0636", "StockNumber": 0, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "74\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631L3\u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 74Ah-N", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000013", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 17, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 0, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "88\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u0628\u0644\u0646\u062f\u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 88Ah-N-Fx", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000014", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 18, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 0, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "90\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631L5\u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 90Ah-N", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000015", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 19, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 2, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "55\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631L2\u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 55Ah-N-NEW", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000016", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 20, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 360, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "60\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u0628\u0644\u0646\u062f\u067e\u06cc\u06a9\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 60Ah-N-NEW", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000017", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 21, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 8, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "66\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631L3\u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 66Ah-N-NEW", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000018", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 22, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 0, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "70\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u0628\u0644\u0646\u062f\u067e\u06cc\u06a9\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 70Ah-N-NEW", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000019", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 23, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 82, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "74\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631L3\u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 74Ah-N-NEW", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000020", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 24, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 96, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "88\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u0628\u0644\u0646\u062f\u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 88Ah-N-Fx-NEW", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000021", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 25, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 1, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "90\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631L5\u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 90Ah-N-NEW", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000022", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 26, "MerchandiseSecondName": "\u0636", "StockNumber": 167, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "100\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 100Ah-N", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000023", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 27, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 249, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "120\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 120Ah-N-Fx", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000024", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 28, "MerchandiseSecondName": "q", "StockNumber": 163, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "150\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u06a9\u0627\u0645\u06cc\u0648\u0646\u06cc \u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 150Ah-N", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000025", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 29, "MerchandiseSecondName": "\u0636", "StockNumber": 112, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "170\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u06a9\u0627\u0645\u06cc\u0648\u0646\u06cc \u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 170Ah-N", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000026", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 30, "MerchandiseSecondName": "\u0636", "StockNumber": 0, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "190\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u06a9\u0627\u0645\u06cc\u0648\u0646\u06cc \u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 190Ah-N", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000027", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 31, "MerchandiseSecondName": "\u0636", "StockNumber": 176, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "200\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u06a9\u0627\u0645\u06cc\u0648\u0646\u06cc \u063a\u06cc\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648 200Ah-N", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000028", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 32, "MerchandiseSecondName": "\u0622\u0628 \u0627\u0633\u06cc\u062f", "StockNumber": 0, "NumberOfOrder": 1111111, "MerchandiseName": "\u0622\u0628 \u0627\u0633\u06cc\u062f", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000029", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 33, "MerchandiseSecondName": "\u0636", "StockNumber": 0, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "\u0628\u0627\u0637\u0631\u06cc \u0636\u0627\u06cc\u0639\u0627\u062a\u06cc \u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u06cc ", "IsSubjectToTax": false, "DetailCode": "2000000030", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": null, "id": 34, "MerchandiseSecondName": "\u0636", "StockNumber": 0, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "\u0628\u0627\u0637\u0631\u06cc \u0636\u0627\u06cc\u0639\u0627\u062a\u06cc \u06a9\u06cc\u0644\u0648\u06cc\u06cc ", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000031", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 35, "MerchandiseSecondName": "70\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u06f2\u06f4\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648\u0633\u064a\u0644\u062f", "StockNumber": 61, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "70\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u06f2\u06f4\u0646\u0627\u0646\u0648\u0633\u064a\u0644\u062f", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000032", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 36, "MerchandiseSecondName": "50\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0631\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u0644 ", "StockNumber": 45, "NumberOfOrder": 144, "MerchandiseName": "50\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0631\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u0644 ", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000033", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 37, "MerchandiseSecondName": "55\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0631\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u0644 ", "StockNumber": 44, "NumberOfOrder": 12, "MerchandiseName": "55\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0631\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u0644 ", "IsSubjectToTax": true, "DetailCode": "2000000034", "EvaluationMethod": 2}, {"OrderPoint": 1, "MerchandiseGroupId": 3, "id": 38, "MerchandiseSecondName": "60\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u06f3\u06f0\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0631\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u0644 ", "StockNumber": 0, "NumberOfOrder": 1, "MerchandiseName": "60\u0622\u0645\u067e\u0631\u06f3\u06f0\u0633\u06cc\u0644\u062f\u0631\u
```